# Pattern matcher behavior change in 11.3

Tags: pattern-matching

When trying to switch from version 10.3 to 11.3 I noticed that some of my code do not work properly. After some investigation I found that the problem is with pattern matcher. Here is the example:

```
toSort = Subsets[Range[13]][[2 ;;]];
gaIndexSort[ind : {{__Integer?Positive} ..}, 
  ord_String: "InvDeg[Lex]"] := "matched"



 gaIndexSort[toSort, "Lex"]
(* not evaluated *)
```

Evaluation in 10.3 and 11.0 works as expected, however in 11.3 message "General::maxrec: Recursion limit exceeded; positive match might be missed."
is issued and the function is not evaluated. Of course, I can change the pattern to, for example,

```
gaIndexSort1[ind : {_List ..}, ord_String: "InvDeg[Lex]"] := 
  "matched1" /; 
   AllTrue[Union[Flatten[ind]], (Positive[#] && IntegerQ[#] &)];



gaIndexSort1[toSort, "Lex"]
(*"matched1"*)
```

Which works as expected. The questions, however, remains 1) is the change intentional and 2) how to effectively match large recursive pattern in most effective way.

Comment: What do you mean by "recursive" pattern? I don't see any recursion, or am I missing something? As for the issue itself: Seems buggy to me, as removing the default value from the second parameter fixes the issue

Comment: @LukasLang I just name it  after message name General::maxrec: which claims that Mma thinks it is recursion somewhere. At least this message is not issued for, say,  toSort = Subsets[Range[10]][[2 ;;]]; or smaller lists.

Comment: The change was intentional, to address crashes from deep recursion in pattern matching. As noted in post, one can address this using more specific patterns that give rise to less need for dynamic backtracking in the pattern matching code.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Can your post this information as an answer?

Comment: Side note: `AllTrue[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[toSort]], (Positive[#] && IntegerQ[#] &)]` is faster than using `Union`. And if you need it sorted, `Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[toSort]]` is faster than `Union`, too, on the example `toSort`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The change was intentional, to address crashes from deep recursion in pattern matching.

As noted in post, one can address this using more specific patterns that give rise to less need for dynamic backtracking in the pattern matching code.

Anecdote: A corporate customer got bitten by it and complained (not terribly loudly, I'm happy to say). But... they were the ones who pushed hardest for the change to begin with.