# Exceeding recursion limit with no obvious recursion: Optional pattern-matching causing nonlocal behavior

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

So, I've come across something strange, and wanted to get a deeper understanding of what was going on. Consider the following code:

```
f[a : {{__}..}, k_ : 0] := 1

a = Table[Table[0, {5}], {10000}]

f[a, 2]
```

So, `f` takes a list of lists and a single optional expression, which can take the default value `0`. This should obviously give `1`, right? After all, the arguments seem ok: `MatchQ[a, {{__}..}]` gives `True`, and even `MatchQ[{a, 2}, {{{__}..}, _}]` gives `True`. More closely, even,

```
MatchQ[{a, 2}, {{{__}..}, _ | PatternSequence[] }]
```

gives `True`.

However, instead of producing `1`, `f[a, 2]` gives an error message "General::maxrec: Recursion limit exceeded; positive match might be missed." and does not evaluate further.

This behavior is also present when defining `Default[f]`. And, indeed,  as soon as we use the `Optional` pattern in `MatchQ[{a,2}, {{__}..}, k_:0}]`, `MatchQ` breaks down and gives the same error message as `f` does. But it can be avoided by removing the default value and providing it in a different (but still definitional) way, e.g.

```
(* Works: *)

f1[a : {{__}..}] := f1[a : {{__}..}, 0]

f1[a : {{__}..}, k_] := 1
```

(Also, it doesn't happen with the shallower pattern `a : {__}`.)

Now, [I'm not the first person to notice this behavior and ask about it here.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202533/pattern-matcher-behavior-change-in-11-3) The answer there says it was an intentional change, and I understand there were probably good reasons—I'm not asking for the rationale, or how to change it. But this is **not** a duplicate question (at least not to that one), because I'm trying to figure something that wasn't asked there:

---

**Why does the `Optional` pattern, e.g. `k_:0`, put a recursion limit on matching the pattern occurring before it? Why does it do so when apparently equivalent pattern matchings (such as `k:(_ | PatternSequence[])`, the alternative implementation of a default value for `f`, or a match made in isolation) don't?**

---

**Note:** A previous version of this question asked why the behavior of pattern matching for function definitions didn't agree with the behavior of pattern matching for `MatchQ`, until @WReach pointed out in the comments that they do, in fact, agree! I simply wasn't using the same pattern verbatim to check.

Possibly related question: the linked answer says something about "dynamic backtracking"; what is that, and is that somehow present for `Optional` matching but not the other working matchings shown here?

Comment: In V12.2 `MatchQ[{a,2}, {a:{{__}..}, k_:0}]` fails in the same way as the function definition and also succeeds if we drop the optional argument value.  So (in 12.2 at least) there is no essential difference between `MatchQ` and a definition.  They both also succeed if we `SetSystemOptions["MaxPatternMatchRecursion"->30005]`. So perhaps the question reduces to: why does adding a default value for the second argument cause the pattern matcher to start back-tracking in the deeper levels of the first argument?

Comment: Its only a guess, but perhaps the presence of the default value causes the pattern matcher to fall back from an optimized special case to a general purpose algorithm.  Variable-length sequences complicate pattern-matching at the best of times, so maybe the presence of default values or other less common patterns cause the matcher to resort to brute force recursive matching.

Comment: I think it is a bug. With n=7998; d = Table[Table[0, {5}], {n}];f[d, 2] it works. But with n=7999 it fails. This is with version 12.1. Please report it to support@wolfram.com

Comment: @DanielHuber It is almost certainly not a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Hi Daniel, I find it  difficult to find a reason why the behavior should depend on the table size.

Comment: @DanielHuber It depends on the table size because the pattern matcher uses a recursive back-tracking algorithm and the recursion depth it can hit depends on that table size.

Comment: @WReach Good point! Not sure why I didn't check the actual pattern in `MatchQ`, lol. I've updated the question to reflect what you've said.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau What I don't understand there is why it can handle the table size in isolated matchings and apparently equivalent matchings, but not matchings that involve `Optional` explicitly.

Comment: I'm not sure offhand. It could be a missed optimization in the pattern matching code internals. I'm not convinced the alternative is exactly equivalent though, since it does not provide a default value. (This might or might not be relevant to whether there is a missed optimization.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That seems plausible. Good point—come to think of it, I don't quite understand how the process of inserting a default value into the matched pattern actually works on a low level.

Comment: At a low level it works by magic, like most of the pattern matcher. (I thought everyone knew that.)